# Pandas 'Replacement not allowed with overlapping keys and values'

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
dftrain
      date        store_nbr   item_nbr  units
0   2012-01-01      1           1         0
1   2012-01-01      1           2         0
2   2012-01-01      2           3         0
3   2012-01-01      3           4         0
4   2012-01-01      4           5         0
...
```

And this dataframe:

```
dfkey
   store_nbr    station_nbr
0   1                1
1   2                1
2   3                4
3   4                1
```

I want to add a column dftrain with a station_nbr column that matches the store number to the station number.

```
 dftrain
       date       store_nbr   item_nbr  units station_nbr
0   2012-01-01      1           1         0        1
1   2012-01-01      1           2         0        1
2   2012-01-01      2           3         0        1
3   2012-01-01      3           4         0        4
4   2012-01-01      4           5         0        1
```

I tried making a dictionary out of dfkey and then using

```
 dftrain.replace(to_replace= mydict)
```

but I got an error I think because some of the stores have the same station number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a merge.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

```
pd.merge(dftrain,dfkey,on='store_nbr',how='left')

         date  store_nbr  item_nbr  units  station_nbr
0  2012-01-01          1         1      0            1
1  2012-01-01          1         2      0            1
2  2012-01-01          2         3      0            1
3  2012-01-01          3         4      0            4
4  2012-01-01          4         5      0            1
```